# error in java SDK Installation

Tags: java

i have already installed jdk1.7.0_55 and now want to install sdk and i have downloaded Java EE 7 SDK with JDK 7 U45 which is the latest in the oracle site.

My JAVA_HOME variable is set in the path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55.

Now when i run the installer of SDK am gettin error in the alert saying

"**could not find the required version of the java(tm) 2 runtime environment in '(null)'** " 
during sdk installation.

Please help me in finding the solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want SDk when you already have jdk?

Comment: i need to work on webservices.. so want to install SDK

Comment: maybe you should download the "Java EE 7 Development Kit Bundles with JDK" found in this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otncn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The versions supported by SDK and the JDK available when do not match, such an error comes. Check for the compatibility of both versions. If you are sure the versions are same, try rebooting your system, set path variables again and try the installer package again.

One thing more make sure you have both the 32 and 64 bits version of JRE installed because the Java EEx64 installer will not work without the 32 bits JRE installation.

Comment: where do i have to install 32 bit jre now? and my java_home variable should point to which path?

Comment: the path as per your system requirements must be set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin . and the simply download the installer of 32 bit installer of JRE and install in the same drive as 64bit installer. It will get things working.

Comment: my JAVA_HOME path is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55 and i installed 32 bit jre installer. was able to install SDK now. But Update Tool Bootstrap :Not Configured .. can i go ahead starting my work or should reinstall again as update tool Bootstrap is not configured

Comment: Yes you can start your work, usually it is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin . The updater can be configured later. Do accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Accepting the answer would be a good gesture if it worked out for you